# Getting fileNotFoundException while doing conn.getInputStream() when connecting android app to server

Tags: android

I am getting file NotFoundException while I am connecting to server through my android code.
Below line is throwing exception.

```
URL url = new URL(PhpFileUrlConstants.PHP_FILE_BASE_URL + PhpFileUrlConstants.INSERT_DOC_INFO_PHP);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data.toString());
//            wr.flush(); 
//            wr.close();
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
//              conn.setDoInput(true);
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Log cat :

07-12 02:48:11.960: W/System.err(2206): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.domainName.com/folder_name/insert_info.php
07-12 02:48:11.980: W/System.err(2206):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
07-12 02:48:12.002: W/System.err(2206):     at com.chlorodots.yourdoc.tasks.DoctorRegistrationTask.doInBackground(DoctorRegistrationTask.java:78)
07-12 02:48:12.010: W/System.err(2206):     at com.chlorodots.yourdoc.tasks.DoctorRegistrationTask.doInBackground(DoctorRegistrationTask.java:1)
07-12 02:48:12.030: W/System.err(2206):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-12 02:48:12.041: W/System.err(2206):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-12 02:48:12.050: W/System.err(2206):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-12 02:48:12.061: W/System.err(2206):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-12 02:48:12.081: W/System.err(2206):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-12 02:48:12.090: W/System.err(2206):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-12 02:48:52.503: D/dalvikvm(403): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 512K, 20% free 3013K/3752K, paused 74ms, total 74ms

Comment: Now which line is throwing the ececption?

Comment: conn.getInputStream()

Comment: Place conn.setDoInput(true); before declaring a stream. So at begin.

Comment: I tried it also but we cant do that as it is showing connection is already open...

Comment: And.. then the exception is not while connecting but when trying to read.

Comment: Please adapt your code for doInput on the place i suggested.

Comment: I tried it by placing before line conn.setDoOutput(true); but still it is showing same fileNotFoundException.....

Comment: And when tried conn.setDoInput(true);
            BufferedReader reader = null;
It is showing illegal state exception and connection is already open message.

Comment: Place it after doOutput.

Comment: What do you expect the server to send? Is the server sending anything to begin with? Keep the flush();.

Comment: Similar code works when I place my server in local machine but When I place it on my internet server it is showing exception...
But when we hit same url in browser the respective file is opening...

Comment: In the browser you cannot do a POST request opening an url. So you cannot compare. It is time to post the stacktrace/logcat.

Comment: Then what might be the problem as It is working fine on local server.

Comment: You should have told right away that it ran ok on local machine. Why spilling time and effort? This is not funny. Is it 'similar code' or the same code?

Comment: And yes it is same code running OK when server is on local machine.

Comment: I wonder how you would mimic domainName.com on your local machine?

Comment: Replaced domainName.com by 10.0.2.2:80 on local machine.

Comment: Thats no answer. On your local machine you have a file ...../folder_name/insert_info.php Why do you think that http://www.domainname.com/folder_name/insert_info.php  exists? The site answers that the page does not exist when i open the url in a browser. How is it possible that you said `But when we hit same url in browser the respective file is opening...`? What did you get? What did you see? What do you get/see now?

Comment: But when I say domainname.com/folder_name/ in browser it lists me all files in that folder and that actually have my required file.

Comment: Is domainname.com fake? Are you using a different name in reality? This  url does not list files: http://www.domainname.com/folder_name  And http://www.domainname.com/folder_name/insert_info.php states page does not exist and that the link should not be used as is from an example.

Comment: I cant mention actual file names as it is confidential.

Comment: Dit you log in once before with your browser for that site?

Comment: @#%-%# Again you should have told before that you used other url's. So you even edited the logcat for it. @€%&# That is two times giving not sufficient info. @&%#@€.

Comment: yes actually we are having running server on that site.

Comment: And we are using that to connect to mysql

Comment: We need to deploy php files on server which we need to connect to our android application.
And that should be web server.
This is one of the solution for such kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky thing with URLConnection is that it will not try to connect and write before you try to grab the input stream. So you think that the exception is at getInputStream but actually it tries to connect then. As you have a FileNotFoundException you can conclude that the url is invalid. Using a browser you get a page but that might be redirected. Well that's for now...